# AWS : Accessing Auto Scaling Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have set up Auto Scaling CLI correctly and also created two groups.
Here is some sample output :

```
-bash-4.1# as-describe-auto-scaling-instances --headers  

INSTANCE INSTANCE-ID GROUP-NAME AVAILABILITY-ZONE STATE STATUS LAUNCH-CONFIG

INSTANCE i-2aaf0e42 MyGroup_micro us-east-1a InService HEALTHY MyLC_micro
INSTANCE i-88338ce4 MyGroup us-east-1a InService HEALTHY MyLC
```

My problems are these :
1. I don't see the above instances in my EC2 Dashboard. Is that okay?
2. Can I login to those instances? If yes, how?

Comment: 1) you should see these in your dashboard. check which region you have selected. 2) using your private key

Comment: @Napalm, Yes it was because of the wrong region.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They should show up on your dashboard. Sometimes not immediately, but it will show eventually
2. Yes, get the ip address to the instance and login with the authentication you have configured.